# Errors starting mysql after moving to a new directory

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-8.0

```
Ubuntu 18.04
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64)
```

I moved my mysql installation from the default `/var/lib/mysql` location to an external drive, using the following:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /media/E
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.bak
```

and then edited the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` file to point the datadir param to its new location `media/E/mysql`.

Attempting to restart mysql, I got:

```
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

On the off chance, I went back and edited the `log_error` param within the `mysql.conf.d` file to point to its new location as well (as it previously pointed to the original `/var/lib/mysql` location).  Still wouldn't start, and left with the following output from `journalctl -xe`:

```
chris@chris-x1c6:/usr/share/mysql$ journalctl -xe
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 audit[26261]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/E/mysql/error.log" pid=26261 comm="mysqld" reque
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 audit[26261]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/E/mysql/error.log" pid=26261 comm="mysqld" reque
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 audit[26261]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/E/mysql/error.log" pid=26261 comm="mysqld" reque
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 audit[26261]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/E/mysql/error.log" pid=26261 comm="mysqld" reque
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 audit[26261]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/E/mysql/error.log" pid=26261 comm="mysqld" reque
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 audit[26261]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/media/E/mysql/error.log" pid=26261 comm="mysqld" reque
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: 2020-02-29T20:36:46.356540Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: 2020-02-29T20:36:46.357247Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /media/E/mysql/chris-x1c6.lower-test
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: 2020-02-29T20:36:46.357287Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 26261 ...
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: 2020-02-29T20:36:46.359205Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /media/E/mysql/chris-x1c6.lower-test
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: 2020-02-29T20:36:46.359247Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /media/E/mysql/chris-x1c6.lower-test
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: 2020-02-29T20:36:46.359818Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/media/E/mysql/error.log' for error logging: Permission denied
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: 2020-02-29T20:36:46.359828Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: 2020-02-29T20:36:46.359846Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 mysqld[26259]: 2020-02-29T20:36:46.359874Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 29 12:36:46 chris-x1c6 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I've found other answers ([here](https://serverfault.com/a/473933), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986591/825227)) that suggest tweaking AppArmor policy settings, but seems a little janky and wonder:

(1) if I did something wrong in moving the existing mysql installation;

(2) whether there's a solution preferable to editing the AppArmor policy file.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, is it possible for you to go back to square 1 - i.e. move everything back into `/var/lib/mysql`?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, but haven't yet.  Is there a better way to do this if I'm in fact able to?

Comment: Just to make sure everything was copied over correctly - if you copy it back (not from backup - you did take a filesystem backup right?) and it works, at least that proves that it's not something missing (or added) during that part of the procedure. Backtracking is a good way to find errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, was able to get it to work using [this approach](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-18-04) *plus* modifying the `log_error` variable within the `mysqld.cnf` file to point to the new location as well.

Adding a line to deal with AppArmor was required (it's included in the linked tutorial), but otherwise works without issue.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to include the relevant bits from the linked page? Link-only (or link-main) answers are frowned upon here - bit rot &c. Just be aware that when you run  stuff from a USB stick/drive, changing machines can be a problem as the host may well assign the stick a different letter/mount point! p.s. welcome to the forum and congrats on solving your own problem! :-)